# How to import csv file into mongoDB where mongo fields have array of array fields

Tags: mongodb

I have a csv dump where I have encoded subarray fields with special characters example : `$@@$`

and I want to convert this string into an array in mongodb after importing csv into it.
Example :

```
"test" : "abc", "info" : [ "abc$@@$def", "pqr$@@$xyz" ]
```

Now i want to split info field elements into array fields using delimiter `$@@$` such that final collection looks like :

```
 "test" : "abc", "info" : [{"name" : "abc", "val" : "def"}, {"name" :
"pqr" , "val" : "xyz"}]
```

How to do it?

Answer (score 0):

like this;
"test" : "abc", "info.name" :"abc",  "info.val" :"def", "info.name.0" :"pqr",  "info.val.0" :"xyz"